# Do the browsers have a maximum height for the body/document?

Tags: html, css, browser

Is there a limitation regarding the height in pixels of an html page?

If so, what are the factors affecting the maximum? Is browser-specific (especially IE7), or maybe client-specific (memory etc.) or anything else.

Comment: Stackoverflow is about programming, so this question (is this really a question?) shouldn't be here. Anyway, from what I know, there is no limitation regarding the height of html pages. However, you should ask yourself if having a very high page is a good practice and provides good user experience.

Comment: @Cthulhu, this is a perfectly valid question, even if having a page billions of pixels high is a terrible idea.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I remember older Netscapes having a physical limit of 32767 pixels for the body. Can't seem to find any links backing that up though.

Comment: Nice question, and I can tell you that Safari 4 won't accept more than 129999999px, firefox is much lower, I just tested it because I was curious, maybe someone else can complete the list: http://jsfiddle.net/8YDTw/

Comment: Actually Safari 4 accepts up to 134217726px! Firefox 3.6 accepts below 16999999px, http://jsfiddle.net/8YDTw/1/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Yes**, there is a technical limit to the height of a page.  (There's also a practical limit – no one can actually use a page that's billions of pixels high, and if your page is that high, you're almost certainly doing something wrong.)

That said, there are actually two different limits to consider: the maximum height of an element that you can specify in CSS, and maximum total height.

Both vary from browser to browser.

[SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki) deals with virtual scrolling, so it has to know the maximum height of an element; [the code it uses to detect this is here](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/36cd54e247ea0dd8175f9ae6a8d7585e15e600a6/slick.grid.js#L378).  I put it in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/BhHfN/): *(these are approximate)*

- Chrome: 512,000,000
- Firefox: 6,000,000
- IE8-9: 1,000,000
- IE6-7: 128,000,000 (yes, *more* than newer IEs)

To test maximum total height, I put together [this test](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/ngnBf/), which fills the page with 11,000 `<div>`s 99,999px in height, for a total of ~1.1 billion pixels of height.

- Chrome seems to lose its marbles around 1.08bn px, and somewhere north of 5bn px, the scrollbar disappears entirely.
- Firefox's scrollbar disappears around 107,398,926 px
- IE is all over the place, with `<div>`s getting misplaced and sized incorrectly.

Comment: I'm running your fiddle test with Chrome 53.0.2785.116 m - it seems to only render the xx pixels up to around 16m px and the scrollbar only goes up to around 33m px. I get nowhere near 1bn px, am i doing something wrong, or limitation of newer version of chrome ?

Answer (score 1):

IE's proprietary CSS `filter:` in IE7 is limited to 4096 pixels. So if you have a large page with an translucent overlay (or any other element using `filter:`), that overlay will only stretch to a maximum of 4096 pixels.